# Where is connection string of federated table stored in mysql?

Tags: mysql, federated

I have many federated tables in my mysql database. I can see the connection string when I open the table structure in dbforge. But i am not able to find where it is stored in mysql.

I checked Information_schema tables and only found the table structures without the connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its either in the table defination (`SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`), or the mysql.servers table (`SHOW SERVERS`).

ref: [how to create federated tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create.html)

Comment: What i am asking is where that is stored. Like in a table in information_schema

Comment: @hiranes read what he wrote before replying like that. He can explain it to you but he can't understand it for you.

Comment: For the table definition its stored in a [frm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html) file (in 5.7, 8.0 changed to a data dictionionary afaik).  For mysql.severs its however the storage engine for the applicable mysql stores its data. Information_schema only exposes information, it doesn't actually store anything. The [information_schema.tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) has  a `CREATE_OPTIONS` field that might contain the table definition form of federated tables.