# Getting federated table connection information

Tags: mysql, federated-storage-engine

I have a number of [federated tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html) on my MySQL 5.7.23 and MariaDB 10.1 servers (I was using [CREATE SERVER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create-server.html) syntax if this matter).

I can easily get a list of these tables using query:

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `ENGINE` = 'Federated';
```

However, I need to get [connection information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create-connection.html) for all these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    -- table definition here
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='server/table' -- <= I would like to get this info
;
```

Not the servers I created that are in `mysql`.`servers`.

I could not find it in `information_schema` and `mysql` databases.

I can only get it from table.frm files or using `SHOW CREATE TABLE table;` query that is for one table only.

Is it possible to get what I want at all?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968975/where-is-connection-string-of-federated-table-stored-in-mysql mentions `mysql.servers`, but doesn't provide any details.

Comment: I'm only using the connection with server. I know where servers stored and how to get them. Actually, I need to check if some servers in the `mysql`.`servers` not used any longer. Right now the only way to do this -- select a list federated tables (as above) and then use `show create table xyz` one by one and read what server mentioned in the table's connection :(